# Backbone history navigate not keeping hash in url

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to use hashes in my urls. when i use the code below, the url goes to kart/:nid but not #kart/:nid as i want it to. I have not enabled pushState:true in my code so that should not be the problem.

Backbone.history.navigate('#kart' + "/" + this.model.get("nid"), { trigger: true});

When i remove the wildcard from the function, the url keeps the hash going to "#kart".

Why is the wildcard messing up this?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: haven't worked with backbone for years, but have you considered setting pushstate to false explicitly?

Comment: yeah tried it, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind. Make sure you aren't explicitly setting `{hashChange: false}` in your code.

If you look at the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) for `navigate`, you'll notice they're not explicitly specifying the hash. So try this instead

`Backbone.history.navigate( "kart/" + this.model.get("nid"), { trigger: true} );`

Comment: did not make any difference unfortunately.. But the problem is not spesific to the navigate function. If i write #kart/10 in the url address bar and hit enter, it automatically goes to kart/10 instead. Can i somehow force it to go to #kart/10? Although it fires the correct route function, i still want it to keep the hash because if i refresh one more time when the url is without the hash, it does not call the correct route

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping guys! i found that the culprit was jquery mobile